# How to create a job in jenkins by using simple Java program

Tags: java, jenkins-cli

I am new to Jenkins, I want to create a new job using Java. Can any one help me?
What are the APIs need to use and is there any sample code?

Comment: does the Jenkins documentation say that it is possible?

Comment: Man, sorry, but there are a bunch of tutorials on Internet.. set Jenkins + Tutorial + Java and you'll find... =)

Comment: can you please suggest me any tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Jenkins REST API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)

### Client code (JAX-WS)

```
Response result = ClientBuilder.newClient()
        .target("http://myserver/jenkins")
        .path("createItem")
        .queryParam("name", "myNewJob")
        .request()
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .post(Entity.entity(jobConfigurationXml(), 
                MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
```

### Job configuration

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders/>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks Mariiusz,i am new to jax-WS i am currently using maven can you please help me through maven plugins(any configuration is required in pom.xml)

Comment: This is no possible with existing Maven plugins

Comment: then,how its connect to jenkins. i want to create a job that job needs to disply on jenkins dashboard.Can you please explain me breafly or if possible please suggest me any tutorial

Comment: Read this document: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Comment: if i execute above code how can i check my job on jenkin dashboard

Comment: I dont understand, it is visible on dashboard

Comment: We are creating job programmatically right.how can i check our newly created job in jenkin dashboard(like any .hpi is generated or....)

Comment: You mean checking programatically?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Sample job info: http://ci.jruby.org/job/jruby-git/api/json?pretty=true for job http://ci.jruby.org/job/jruby-git/

Comment: Actually,i am very new to jenkins Thats why i am unable to understand through those links.i need just a sample code to create a job and how can i see that job on my jenkin dashboard

Comment: Your question is about creating job, the code is attached. Ask another question for other your troubles.

Comment: i am trying to create a job by using command java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ create-job new job....but it is keep on running it doesnt give any output